# Need to write files to disk, how can I reference the folder in a web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

In a web application, that may be installed anywhere on the filesystem, I need to figure out the path to the root of the installation folder.

I want to write xml files to the directory:

```
c:/installation/path/web_app/files/
```

Is this possible or do I have to store this path in the web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Server.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx)

as in

```
Server.MapPath("~/files/ ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "web_app" in your example is always the root folder of your web application, you can reference the files like...

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/files/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var rootFolder = Server.MapPath("~")` to retrieve the physical path.

The tilde character `~` is replaced with the root directory of your web application, e.g. `c:\installation\path\web_app`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx